# Backing up Minio to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, minio

I'm setting up distributed Minio servers locally to use in a solution but would like to back them up to S3 regularly in case the local file system fails/just for more durability or just to migrate to AWS. The use case being we need an S3 compatible storage locally for regular access but would like the option of having it backed up in the cloud.

Wanted to check if anyone has tried something similar before or knows of something similar? Like a simple way/tool to keep Minio buckets in sync with your S3 buckets?

Answer (score 4):

you can simply use `mc mirror` between minio/ to s3/

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out Rclone https://rclone.org/ - Rclone is a command line program to sync files and directories to and from: ... minio ... s3 (and lots more).

Combine this with either a batch or cron job or something based on minio notifications triggered on update/delete.